# forwarding reference with containers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue, lvalue

It's possible that give `std::vector<T>` e.g to function by forwarding reference? 
I know that

```
template<typename T>
void f(const std::vector<T>&&){} // is rvalue
template<typename T>
void f(const std::vector<T>&){} // is lvalue
```

but how I can make function for lvalue and rvalue (with std::vector as parametr)?

Comment: I am a little rusty on this but I believe that a in a function of the form: `void f(T&&)` will only be a "universal reference" if T is an "unknown" type (like a template parameter)

Comment: Are you asking if the parameters of the template functions, as you've shown them, are universal references? (as per Scott Meyers' definition, who I believe invented the term)

Comment: Please use full sentences so that we can tell what you're asking.

Comment: Meyers coined the term in his effective modern c++ book. The c++ powers that be now call them forwarding references.

Comment: @21koizyd: Someone invented every term!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
// traits for detecting std::vector
template <typename> struct is_std_vector : std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename A>
struct is_std_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_std_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value>
f(T&&); // Take any std::vector
```

Comment: I though about this but I had make sure. Thanks.

Comment: Okey, I was implemented that but i have problem with return value from function if I want, i tried `typename std::enable_if_t<is_std_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value>::type`, but doesn't work in this case. Type of course (`T` - input)